# Jest test coverage gives 100% coverage for modules that have no tests at all

Tags: jestjs, code-coverage

I'm experiencing 2 issues with Jest test coverage:

1- Jest reports 100% (Stmts, Branch, Func, and Lines) coverage for modules with no tests at all but required by tested modules

2- Jest reports 100% Branch coverage for modules with no tests nor required by tested modules

In the image:

- sum is a tested module
- toNum is not tested but required by sum
- sub is neither tested nor required by tested modules

I've create a repo that reproduces the issue:
https://github.com/hossamnasser938/Reproduce-Jest-Coverage-Issue

Here is my package.json:
[image]

Here is my folder structure:
[image]

How do I remove the entry for `sub.js` from the coverage report? I really appreciate your help.[image: jest test coverage]

Comment: This is most likely by design given your config, test, and source code which you haven't shown.

Comment: What do you mean by "most likely by design"? Is is the default behavior of Jest? @morganney

Comment: Include your jest config. The answers to your questions are there. By the way, you haven't asked a question yet.

Comment: Actually, I created a minimal repo with minimal Jest configurations to see if the issue exists or not and it is there. Anyway, I've attached Jest config in the question @morganney

Comment: Ok, so what question would you like answered? If you want the tests to ignore files that don't have tests then update your config for `collectCoverageFrom`.

Comment: I'm specifying `src/**/*.js` in `collectCoverageFrom`. What should I do? @morganney

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1- Jest reports 100% (Stmts, Branch, Func, and Lines) coverage for modules with no tests at all but required by tested modules

This is expected behavior when you configure Jest to collect coverage. The required modules are still executed by your test, despite them not having a test of their own. The documentation for [`collectCoverage`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#collectcoverage-boolean) states

> this retrofits all executed files with coverage collection statements

Your test is executing all of the code from the required module, so the module is covered completely, 100% by your test code. Even though the module is executed by another test, you should still write a separate test for the required module to ensure it works in isolation as a unit.

> 2- Jest reports 100% Branch coverage for modules with no tests nor required by tested modules

Again this is expected behavior given your configuration value for [`collectCoverageFrom`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#collectcoveragefrom-array) which includes `sub.js`, and your implementation of sub which has no branching, so `Branch` statements would be 100% executed (because there are none).

If you want Jest to stop reporting on `sub.js` then you have a couple of options:

- Remove the configuration for `collectCoverageFrom` entirely, and
  that will remove the entry for `sub.js` from the coverage report
  table.
- Modify your value for `collectCoverageFrom` to specifically
  ignore `sub.js`:

  ```js
  collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.js', '!src/**/sub.js']
  ```

Personally, I would leave everything as-is to serve as a reminder that `sub.js` still needs to be tested with adequate coverage.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really informative

Comment: Really informative indeed. But seems that coverage is nearly useless in the real world to drive our tests…